# How to trigger alarmManager's initial run after specific duration?

Tags: android

I need to trigger an alarmManager's first run at the start of next minute. for example, if the current time is 6:47:40 seconds, then the alarmManager's first run will trigger at 6:48:00 (i.e. 20 seconds later)

To achieve this I need to figure out how many second is left for the current minute to complete. this can be done using this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int secondsTillNextMinute = 60 - c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Now How can I use this value in the alarmmanager.SetRepeating? My alarmManager looks like this.

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), 60000, createClockTickIntent(context));

private PendingIntent createClockTickIntent(Context context) {
Intent intent = new Intent(CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
return pendingIntent;
}
```

I want to use `secondsTillNextMinute` instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()` in my SetRepeating code. How do I do that? the 2nd parameter accepts only milisecond values?

Comment: `at the start of next minute` ... so, why do you have to calculate the seconds to **00**? If the current minute is **47:xy**, next minute is **48:00**. Simply, don't take in account the seconds ad **just add 1 to the current minute**.

Comment: Hi Der Golem, I need to trigger some action EXACTLY when the minute value changes after user adds an widget in home screen.

Comment: `EXACTLY when the minute value changes` means at (Minute+1):00

Comment: Actually user may add the widget at 10:12:30 sec (i.e. 30 sec until the next minute), or at 10:12:45 sec (15 seconds till next minute) so I never know how many seconds I need to wait before triggering the action, so I need to make it decide in run time. It's a stopwatch widget so per second precession is required.

Comment: I have updated the title. I guess it was confusing :-/

Comment: `(i.e. 30 sec until the next minute), or at 10:12:45 sec (15 seconds till next minute)` ... NEXT MINUTE starts always at **:00**. i.e.: 10:13:00, in both cases. So, `at the start of next minute.` you only need to calculate the next minute

Comment: Ok got it now :-) thank you, but can you please let me know how to I convert the next minute to miliseconds so that I can use it in Setrepeating?

Comment: int next_minute = (current_minute + 1) * 1000;

Comment: But wont the above code will output the same value for both 12:48 and 1:48 and 2:48 and so on? the documentation says the 2nd parameter is not duration, it's time.

Comment: you must also calculate the hours, of course. In this case you must know if the hour remains unchanged or it changes (it will change when next minute is 0, so simply add 1 to the hour). The hour must be multiplied by 60000 and added to the next minute.